# Slow opening SQLite connection in C# app using System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, file-io, system.data.sqlite, network-service

## Edit 3:

I guess my issue is resolved for the moment... I changed both my service and test app to run as the `SYSTEM` account instead of the `NetworkService` account.  It remains to be seen if the benefits of changing the user account will persist, or if it will only be temporary.

### Original Question:

I've noticed that my small 224kB SQLite DB is very slow to open in my C# application, taking anywhere from some small number of ms, to 1.5 seconds or more.  Below is my code, with all the extra debugging statements I've added this afternoon.  I've narrowed it down to the call to `cnn.Open();` as shown in the logs here:

```
2014-03-27 15:05:39,864 DEBUG - Creating SQLiteConnection...
2014-03-27 15:05:39,927 DEBUG - SQLiteConnection Created!
2014-03-27 15:05:39,927 DEBUG - SQLiteConnection Opening...
2014-03-27 15:05:41,627 DEBUG - SQLiteConnection Opened!
2014-03-27 15:05:41,627 DEBUG - SQLiteCommand Creating...
2014-03-27 15:05:41,627 DEBUG - SQLiteCommand Created!
2014-03-27 15:05:41,627 DEBUG - SQLiteCommand executing reader...
2014-03-27 15:05:41,658 DEBUG - SQLiteCommand executed reader!
2014-03-27 15:05:41,658 DEBUG - DataTable Loading...
2014-03-27 15:05:41,767 DEBUG - DataTable Loaded!
```

As you can see, in this instance it took 1.7 SECONDS to open the connection.  I've tried repeating this, and cannot predict whether subsequent connections will open nearly immediately, or be delayed like this.

I've considered using some form of connection pooling, but is it worthwhile to pursue that for a single-instance single-threaded application?  Right now, I'm creating an instance of my SQLiteDatabase class, and calling the below function for each of my queries.

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        Logging.LogDebug("Creating SQLiteConnection...");
        using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
        {
            Logging.LogDebug("SQLiteConnection Created!");
            Logging.LogDebug("SQLiteConnection Opening...");
            cnn.Open();
            Logging.LogDebug("SQLiteConnection Opened!");
            Logging.LogDebug("SQLiteCommand Creating...");
            using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn))
            {
                Logging.LogDebug("SQLiteCommand Created!");
                mycommand.CommandText = sql;
                Logging.LogDebug("SQLiteCommand executing reader...");
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Logging.LogDebug("SQLiteCommand executed reader!");
                    Logging.LogDebug("DataTable Loading...");
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    Logging.LogDebug("DataTable Loaded!");
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

### Edit:

Sure, `dbConnection` is the connection string, set by the following function.  `inputFile` is just the string path of the filename to open.

```
public SqLiteDatabase(String inputFile)
{
    dbConnection = String.Format("Data Source={0}", inputFile);
}
```

And at this point, I think `sql` is irrelevant, as it's not making it to that point when the cnn.Open() stalls.

### Edit 2:

Ok, I've done some more testing.  Running the testing locally, it completes a 1000 iteration loop in ~5 seconds, for about 5ms per call to `cnn.Open()`. Running the test from the same windows installer that I did on my local PC, it completes in ~25 minutes, averaging 1468ms per call to `cnn.Open()`.

I made a small test program that only calls the `TestOpenConn()` function from the service program (same exact code that is running in the Windows service), running against a copy of the file located in a test directory.  Running this on the server or my local PC results in acceptable performance (1.95ms per call on the server, 4ms per call on my local PC):

```
namespace EGC_Timing_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Logging.Init("log4net.xml", "test.log");
            var db = new SqLiteDatabase("config.sqlite");
            db.TestOpenConn();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the test function:

```
public void TestOpenConn()
{
    // TODO: Remove this after testing loop of opening / closing SQLite DB repeatedly:
    const int iterations = 1000;
    Logging.LogDebug(String.Format("Running TestOpenConn for {0} opens...", iterations));
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
        {
            Logging.LogDebug(String.Format("SQLiteConnection Opening, iteration {0} of {1}...", i, iterations));
            var startTimeInner = DateTime.Now;
            cnn.Open();
            var endTimeInner = DateTime.Now;
            var diffTimeInner = endTimeInner - startTimeInner;
            Logging.LogDebug(String.Format("SQLiteConnection Opened in {0}ms!", diffTimeInner.TotalMilliseconds));
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
    var endTime = DateTime.Now;
    var diffTime = endTime - startTime;
    Logging.LogDebug(String.Format("Done running TestOpenConn for {0} opens!", iterations));
    Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("{0} iterations total:\t{1}", iterations, diffTime));
    Logging.LogInfo(String.Format("{0} iterations average:\t{1}ms", iterations, diffTime.TotalMilliseconds/iterations));
}
```

Comment: The database is in your local pc or in a remote server?

Comment: It is a local sqlite db file, no network involved

Comment: Could you paste the value of `dbConnection` and `sql` ?

Comment: Added the requested code to my question

Comment: Which version of System.Data.SQLite are you using? Is there a lot of disk contention - is it consistently 1.7 seconds? What else is running on the machine? Is it a fast SSD or a dying old HDD. There are far too many variables to consider.

Comment: After noticing the problem, I swapped out the old version of System.Data.SQLite that I was using (1.0.87.0) for the latest version via NuGet (1.0.92.0).  It is running on an enterprise VM as our Development server, with nothing else running on this VM.  The storage is provided by an enterprise SAN.  I'm updating my question with some timing tests that I've started, using my SQLite DB file.

Comment: Investigating if it may be an AV related issue, as my timing test version has "suddenly" started taking just as long as the windows service version.  Something odd is going on here, and it's probably not related to SQLite in any way.

Comment: Ok, I had our AV admin temporarily disable McAfee and re-ran my test, but no change.

Comment: I noticed that when I ran the test app as myself, the file open times were as expected, but when I ran it under the `Network Service` account via Task Scheduler it is running slowly every time.  I just changed the scheduled task to run as the `SYSTEM` account and it completed quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess my issue is resolved for the moment... I changed both my service and test app to run as the `SYSTEM` account instead of the `NetworkService` account. It remains to be seen if the benefits of changing the user account will persist, or if it will only be temporary.

Comment: I confirm that switching to SYSTEM solves the issue. Quite odd though.
Did you find any explanation to this behavior?

Comment: @AndreyVoitenkov I never did find any explanation, but 6 months after this post I changed my application to use our MSSQL server, and haven't investigated further on the SQLite issue...

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using the open source [`System.Data.SQLite`](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) library.

If that's the case, it's easy to see through the Visual Studio Performance Profiler that the `Open` method of the `SQLiteConnection` class has some serious performance issues.
Also, have a lookthrough the source code for this class here: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/97648754af51ffd6

There's an awful lot of disk access being made to read XML configuration and Windows environment variable(s).

My suggestion is to try and call `Open()` as seldom as possible, and try and keep a reference to this open `SQLiteConnection` object around in memory.
A performance ticket is raised with [`SQLite Forum`](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/be12568e30af55ac0f31ee1109ebce0e0a2bc3a3)

Answer (score 1):

Having had the same problem, I was looking into this and it seems to be related to permissions on the file or it's parent folders, who created it, and/or how it was created. In my case, the SQLite database file was being created by a script run as a regular user, and then an IIS-hosted service would access the file under a different domain service account.

Every time the service opened a connection, it took over 1.5 seconds, but otherwise operated correctly (it could eventually access the file). A stand-alone program running as the regular user could open a connection to the same file in the same place in a few milliseconds.

Analysis of a procmon trace revealed that in the case of the service, we were getting several ACCESS DENIED logs on the file over the course of about 1.5 seconds, that were not present in the trace when running as the regular user.

Not sure what's going on there. The service worked fine and was able to eventually query the data in the file, albeit slowly.

When we made the service account the owner of the parent folder of the file, and gave him write permission, the ACCESS DENIED logs disappeared and the service operated at full speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Modify" permissions of appropriate user to folder with your database.
Right Click on folder > Properties > Security > Edit > Add (I added IIS_Users) > Select "Modify" checkbox > OK